# Bulk insert in PGSQL with master-child relation

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am migrating data from old schema to updated schema (PG as new database in place).

I am using C# to automate this process.

Here is a screenshot that shows original data (sample to understand).

[image]

Based on updated schema, this source data need to be separated into two tables `Vehicles` and `PartPricing`.
The unique combination of Make, Model and Year will be inserted into `Vehicles` and linked with unique Id.
The Part and PartPrice will then be inserted into `PartPricing` table and need to be linked with `VehicleId`. (VehicleId refers to Id of Vehicles table)

Below screen shows the expected output.
[image]

**The approach i followed** is -

1. Get the unique list of Make, Model and Year and generate bulk insert query and execute.
2. Fetch all the inserted vehicles and cache into a collection.
3. Now loop through each line item in the source
4. Lookup for VehicleId based on Make, Model and Year (from within collection and not from database)
5. Prepare insert statement for PartPricing
6. After loop completes, execute the bulk insert query for PartPricing.

Although the Vehicles data is inserted pretty quickly but the preparation of bulk insert for PartPricing is taking considerable amount of time due to lookup.

Is there a better alternative to this problem? please suggest.

Just FYI, when i say bulk insert it follows -

```
Insert into Vehicles(Make, Model, Year) values
('Honda', 'City', 2010),
('Honda', 'City', 2011),
('Hyundai', 'Accent', 2011),
....
('Toyota', 'Corolla', 2015);
```

Comment: Perhaps a missing index: `CREATE INDEX ON vehicles (make, model, year);`

Comment: When you create a database there is tradeoff between amount of memory and the time to retrieve.  Your new approach take lets memory because you are not repeating parts that are used on more than one vehicle, but it take more time to retrieve data because you have to join two tables.

Comment: I have updated point #4, just to clear that I am not querying on database. Instead all the Vehicle data is cached into memory (through collection) which is then used to lookup for vehicle id using LINQ.